# Require returning object and not string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to import an image in React, using

```
<Parallax filter image={require("assets/img/DataServer.jpg")}></Parallax>
```

but instead of a string, it returns

```
Module {default: "/static/media/DataServer.bed2accd.jpg", __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

How do I resolve this?

Note: I have set NODE_PATH=./src, and assets is in src/

Comment: React or not doesn't matter. What build system/transpiler are you using, what module syntax (ES6 vs commonjs), and where do you run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this structure :

```
/src
    /assets
    ...component
```

import like modules :

```
import DataServerImage  from "./assets/img/DataServer.jpg";
```

then use :

```
<Parallax filter image={DataServerImage}></Parallax>
```

Comment: i thinks u should point the folder with `./` , then require works also: `image={require("./assets/img/DataServer.jpg")}`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
import img from "assets/img/DataServer.jpg"
<Parallax filter image={img}}></Parallax>
```

`img` will be resolved to the image path.